# Can not catch Selenium WebDriverException on navigate url

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium in C# and I have a little problem with my latest test I wrote.

I create a new FirefoxDriver which navigates to my URL, which instantly creates a popup for authentication before it navigates further. Problem here is, that driver.navigate().gotourl("") does wait for the URL to be load, which it doesn't - and also shouldn't - do. When I surround this statement with a try catch block to catch the WebDriverException it just ignores it and ends my test with:

```
Test Name:  SetUserPw
Test FullName:  XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGui.PasswordTest.SetUserPw
Test Source:    C:\Programme\IMaT\TestPlugins\Plugins for XUnit\XUnit_DataManager_Tests\DataManagerGui\PasswordTest.cs : line 393
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,001

Result StackTrace:  
bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTargetLocator.Alert()
   bei WebsiteAutomation.Helpers.Helper.c.b__4_0(IWebDriver drv)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   bei WebsiteAutomation.Helpers.Helper.WaitForAlert(UInt32 timeout)
   bei WebsiteAutomation.Helpers.Helper.WaitForBasicAuth(String user, String password, Boolean accept, UInt32 timeout)
   bei XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGui.PasswordTest.OpenPasswordSite(String password) in C:\Programme\IMaT\TestPlugins\Plugins for XUnit\XUnit_DataManager_Tests\DataManagerGui\PasswordTest.cs:Zeile 430.
   bei XUnit_DataManager_Tests.DataManagerGui.PasswordTest..ctor(InverterFixture fixtureData) in C:\Programme\IMaT\TestPlugins\Plugins for XUnit\XUnit_DataManager_Tests\DataManagerGui\PasswordTest.cs:Zeile 36.
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
Result Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:7055/hub/session/4b47ded2-6ba6-4052-8785-e8ba346092da/alert_text timed out after 60 seconds.
---- System.Net.WebException : Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen: Timeout für Vorgang überschritten.
```

Is there a way to navigate to a URL, but react on the authentication popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle an alert when the page is loading:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// set the timeout to 0 and catch it
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
try{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("...");
}catch(WebDriverTimeoutException){
    driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();
}
// restore the timeout
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

Comment: Latest C# selenium has replaced the SetPageLoadTimeout function with the get/set property PageLoad.  No matter.  Just what I needed.